# How to find correct match position

Tags: c#, text, compare

I would like to find match

I prefer to "IndexOf" (not RegExp or something, becuase it is pretty simple codes).

I have a problem with strange character.
The situation is Given, I can not control it.

Let's see the screenshot, that is good enough.

It should make result "-1" but it makes not "-1" (0 in this case).

Thanks.

```
string myString1 = "abc";
string myString2 = "abc�";
MessageBox.Show(
    "Result \n" + 
    myString1.IndexOf(myString2));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60i8g.png)

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are trying to do. It would be helpful if you include any code in the question, not as a picture of code, as some assistive technologies may not be able to read the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `StringComparison.Ordinal`

```
string myString1 = "abc";
string myString2 = "abc�";

MessageBox.Show("Result \n" + myString1.IndexOf(myString2, StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

It's just on of those weird "gotchas" that shows using culture information can sometimes really matter.